# Lucene.net return all fields in a document

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am storing data in lucene.Net
I add a document with multiple fields :

```
var doc = new Document();

doc.Add(new Field("CreationDate", dt, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("FileName", path, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Directory", dtpath, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Text", text.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
...
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

I want to move through all items and return fields "CreationDate" and "Directory" for each document.
But a Term can only except 1 field :

var termEnum = reader.Terms(new Term("CreationDate"));

How do i make it return the 2 fields ???

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over search results, read the document and load the values from it:

```
int docId = hits[i].doc;  
Document doc = searcher.Doc(docId); 
String creationDate = doc.Get("CreationDate");
String directory = doc.get("Directory");
// ...and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ontain a enumeration of all documents containing a given term with:

```
var termDocEnum = reader.TermDocs(new Term("CreationDate"));
```

You can use that enumeration to fetch documents using the docId:

```
Document doc = searcher.doc(termDocEnum.doc);
```

Which should make it easy enough to use the [Document API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html) to get the information you are looking for.

Note, as hinted at earlier, this will only get documents for which the term given has a value specified!  If that is a problem, you can either call TermDocs once for each pertinent argument and merge the sets as needed (done easily enough with a hash table indexed on docId, or some such), or call TermDocs with no argument, and use [seek](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/TermDocs.html#seek%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term%29) to find the appropriate Terms (merging will again need to be done manually if necessary).

A TermEnum, as passed from the 'terms' method does not give you a docId (you would have to use the termDocs method to get them with each term in the enum, I believe.)